# Highcharts - Adding css to highcharts legend

Tags: highcharts

I am attempting to customize my Highcharts legend to html with in line style tag in order to change the color using `this.color`

I am using

```
labelFormatter: function () {
                    return  "Total amount of  <b style='" + this.color + ">" + this.name + " Percentage"
            }
```

in attempt to accomplish this. I would like the legend of graph to display "Total amount of LOW Percentage" I am able to accomplish this but I am now trying to add styling to "LOW", "MEDIUM" or "HIGH" which is coming from this.name; I would like to make that color the same color that it is in the graph such as :

LOW = Green,

MEDIUM = Orange

HIGH = RED

I attempted to accomplish this by using this.color but it did not have any affect on my legend.

Here is a jsfiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/uyr2tb7n/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned string should look like this:

```
    legend: {
        ...,
        labelFormatter: function() {
            return "Total amount of  <span style='color:" + this.color + "'>" + this.name + "</span> Percentage"
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jv3p5z8t/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter